# Return only duplicate values in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having trouble trying to return only duplicate values in a query on Microsoft Access.

Here is my initial query:

```
SELECT tbl_dbextract_GP.GPNo, 
    [tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPFirst]+" "+[tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPLast] AS GPName, 
    Sum(tbl_main_ListLog.count_ToImport) AS ImportCount, 
    tbl_main_ListLog.SearchSequence
FROM ((tbl_main_ListLog
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GPPractice 
    ON tbl_main_ListLog.GPPracticeID = tbl_dbextract_GPPractice.Id) 
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GP 
    ON tbl_dbextract_GPPractice.GPId = tbl_dbextract_GP.Id)
WHERE tbl_dbextract_GP.GPNo <> 'G0000'
GROUP BY tbl_dbextract_GP.GPNo, 
    [tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPFirst]+" "+[tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPLast], 
    tbl_main_ListLog.SearchSequence;
```

I only want to return results where there is at least 2 entries per GPNo. 
The search sequence is incremental, so basically I am trying to find entries where there has been at least 2 searches.

This was my attempt:

```
SELECT
    tbl_dbextract_GP.GPNo,
    [tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPFirst] + " " + [tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPLast] AS GPName,
    Sum(tbl_main_ListLog.count_ToImport) AS ImportCount,
    tbl_main_ListLog.SearchSequence
FROM (((tbl_main_ListLog
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GPPractice 
    ON tbl_main_ListLog.GPPracticeID = tbl_dbextract_GPPractice.Id) 
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GP 
    ON tbl_dbextract_GPPractice.GPId = tbl_dbextract_GP.Id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tbl_main_ListLog.GPPracticeID as GPPID, 
        SUM(tbl_main_ListLog.SearchSequence) as SumSS
    FROM tbl_main_ListLog
    WHERE SumSS > 1
    GROUP BY tbl_main_ListLog.GPPracticeID) SubQ 
ON tbl_main_ListLog.GPPracticeID = SubQ.GPPID)
WHERE tbl_dbextract_GP.GPNo <> 'G0000'
GROUP BY tbl_dbextract_GP.GPNo, 
[tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPFirst]+" "+[tbl_dbextract_GP].[GPLast], 
tbl_main_ListLog.SearchSequence;
```

This didn't work, as it prompted me to manually enter the value for SumSS on execute, and that didn't return the right results anyway.

This is a sample output (Names redacted) - I want to return results where there is at least 2 entries per GPNo

[image: This is a sample output (Names redacted) - I want to return results where there is at least 2 entries per GPNo]

EDIT: Modified attempt using Tim's solution - returning "Syntax error in JOIN operation":

```
SELECT
    t3.GPNo, 
    t3.GPFirst + " " + t3.GPLast AS GPName,
    SUM(t1.count_ToImport) AS ImportCount, 
    t1.SearchSequence
FROM (((tbl_main_ListLog t1
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GPPractice t2 
    ON t1.GPPracticeID = t2.Id)
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GP t3 
    ON t2.GPId = t3.Id)
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t3.GPNo
    FROM ((tbl_main_ListLog t1
    INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GPPractice t2
        ON t1.GPPracticeID = t2.Id)
    INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GP t3
        ON t2.GPId = g3.Id)
    GROUP BY t3.GPNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t4
    ON t3.GPNo = t4.GPNo)
WHERE
    t3.GPNo <> 'G0000'
GROUP BY
    t3.GPNo, 
    t3.GPFirst + " " + t3.GPLast, 
    t1.SearchSequence;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is MS Access, which does not support analytic functions, doing a join to another subquery to impose the restriction on the number of searches seems like a reasonable approach, and your second attempt does not look far off.  But you should be using the `HAVING` operator instead of `WHERE`, with a few other changes:

```
SELECT
    t3.GPNo, 
    t3.GPFirst + " " + t3.GPLast AS GPName,
    SUM(t1.count_ToImport) AS ImportCount, 
    t1.SearchSequence
FROM tbl_main_ListLog t1
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GPPractice t2 
    ON t1.GPPracticeID = t2.Id
INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GP t3 
    ON t2.GPId = t3.Id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t3.GPNo
    FROM tbl_main_ListLog t1
    INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GPPractice t2
        ON t1.GPPracticeID = t2.Id
    INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GP t3
        ON t2.GPId = t3.Id
    GROUP BY t3.GPNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t4
    ON t3.GPNo = t4.GPNo
WHERE
    t3.GPNo <> 'G0000'
GROUP BY
    t3.GPNo, 
    t3.GPFirst + " " + t3.GPLast, 
    t1.SearchSequence;
```

In the subquery which I have aliased as `t4`, I do the same set of joins as your original query, but I then aggregate only by the `GPNo`.  Also, I added a `HAVING` clause requiring that a `GPNo` appear two or more times in order to be retained in the result set.  This subquery then filters off non matching `GPNo` records in your original query.

Comment: @dweeman I don't know Access very well.  Feel free to edit my answer if you can fix the query.  In ANSI SQL terms, what I wrote should work.

Comment: No worries, I'll give it a go. Access SQL syntax is quite annoying and bloated, and difficult to debug. I'll let you know if I can make it work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably need to wrap parentheses around something.

Comment: I've added the changes to your code I did to resolve the errors I was facing, but now I get a Syntax error in JOIN operation. Can't spot where the issue would be. See edit in original post

Comment: @dweeman I had a _typo_ in my answer: `ON t2.GPId = g3.Id` ... should be `ON t2.GPId = t3.ID` ... remove it and it should work.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that either! Perfect, thanks so much for that. I'll keep in mind the HAVING function in future.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Count(1) As Countr` to your query and apply condition `Countr>1` (apply `HAVING` clause as explained above).

Alternatively, in order to simplify your task, you can save the original working query as the intermediate one, e.g. `Sub_With_Duplicates` (Access has that feature), and then build another one (eg. `Qry_No_Duplicates` on the top of the intermediate and simply apply `WHERE` `Countr>1` clause to that field. This should work.

Comment: In the initial select?

Comment: Please see the extended answer.